# Sending posts with a specific category to the view in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making a blog in Laravel Framework. I want to send posts to the frontend view that have a specific category. How can i do this when i have a separate category table that is connected to the posts table?
For example, my posts table has a category_id that is connected to the category table.

Post model:

```
public function category(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Category model:

```
public function posts(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Now, how can i send posts to the view, but only posts that have a specific category, for example "Archive"?

I know it should be something like:

```
public function index()
{

    $rows = Post::notdeleted()->get();

    return view('admin.posts.index', compact('rows'));
}
```

but i dont know how to get the category since it is a category_id 1 in posts table and "archive" in category table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to  filter the post by category name.

```
public function index(){
  // For example Archive
  $categoryName= request()->get('category_name');
  $posts = Post::whereHas('category',function($query) use ($categoryName){
     $query->where('name','like',"%{$categoryName}%");
  }); 
  return view('admin.posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $rows = Post::whereHas('category',function($q){
            $q->where('category_name','archive');
        })->get();
        return view('admin.posts.index', compact('rows'));
    }
```